# Let A ⊆ B. Prove that if A is uncountable, then B is also uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

For proving that A ⊆ B, if A is uncountable, then B is also uncountable, I simply would like to start from the definitions of bijection and countable sets and then proving by contradiction that the requirements mentioned have consequences for the uncountable sets as well.

I wonder if I can start the proof from the assumptions stated in this way:

From the definition of bijection, we know that if A bijects in B, B bijects in A (I don't know how to do tilde on keyboard). **From the definition of countable sets, we know that if A is countable and B is a substet of A, then B is also countable** (I wonder if I should give more evidence about this last statement in bold characters or if I may write it more clearly, showing that it is a consequence of the definitions of countable and bijection).

After stated these postulates, I might prove "Let A ⊆ B. Prove that if A is uncountable, then B is also uncountable" **by contradiction** in simple way:

Assume that subset A is uncountable and superset B is countable. For B to be countable means that bijects in N and that its subsets are also countable. But A is uncountable. This disprove our assumption about B, therefore B is also uncountable.

PS. However, am I wrong if I say that the whole theory tells us only that an uncountable set cannot be a subset of a countable set but, on the other hand, an uncountable set can be the superset of countable sets. i.e. isn't it the case of R with respect to Q, Z and N?

Comment: What exactly _is_ your definition of "countable"? There are several possible ones, mostly equivalent but different enough that "from the definition of countable" can make excellent sense for one of them but hide several missing steps for anohter one.

Comment: The general definition is that a set is countable if it is possible to find a bijection between the elements of the set and the set of N.

Comment: I thoought all the related properties could be proved starting from this assumption but I am not studying all proofs of real analysis, although reading many of them.

Comment: If your definition of countable is as you defined above then your first bold sentence is not true. I would also point out that from the definition it is not all that obvious that it should be true even if you fix the notational issue. If I have a bijection $A\to\mathbb{N}$ it is not clearly obvious that i have a bijection $B\to\mathbb{N}$ for $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: In that case I think your bolded "From the definition of countable sets" needs to be replaced by a more detailed argument. In fact the bolded claim is not even true -- if we take $A=\mathbb N$ and $B=\{42\}$ then certainly $A$ is countable (being in bijection with itself), and certainly $B\subseteq A$, but $B$ is not in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Right... Thank you for your remark!

Comment: Could I have some more answers which clarify to me how to improve the proof according to the style I have already given to it, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the contrapositive statement (which is equivalent): if $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is countable, then $A$ is countable. This is much easier, don't you think?

If $f: B \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection, then you construct a bijection $f: A \to f(A)$ simply restricting $f$. So you have to show that $f(A) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Define recursively $$x_0 = \min f(A)$$ and $$x_{n+1} = \min f(A) \setminus \{ x_0, \dots , x_n\}$$

The map $\mathbb{N} \to f(A)$ defined by $n \mapsto x_n$ is a bijection (check).

Answer (score 1):

For every infinite set $A$ there exists an injective map $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to A$. If $B$ is countable, then there is a bijection $g\colon B\to \mathbb{N}$ (an injection would suffice). If $i\colon A\to B$ denotes the inclusion map, we have the injection $g\circ i\colon A\to\mathbb{N}$.

The injections $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to A$ and $g\circ i\colon A\to\mathbb{N}$, together with Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein tell that…